# Open file when dragged on Python script file

Tags: python, file

I wondered, how can I open a file when this one is dragged onto the Python script icon so I can use `File = open("File directory")` with this file (Not talking of the Python Shell but of a `.py`script made next to it)?

Comment: I don't even have code for this, I know how to open a file but I have no idea of how I can make this...

Comment: You don't have a script with the `Python script icon`? And a `.py` script made "next to" the Python Shell? There's a lot in your question that, on the surface, doesn't seem to make sense. Could you rephrase it to help us understand a little better?

Comment: When I tried dragging a file on top of a little Python script test script I wrote, `sys.argv[1]` contained the full path to the file (on my Windows OS system).